# Any use for old CLEAR (WiMAX) modems?

Tags: wireless

[CLEAR](http://www.clear.com), the major [WiMAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMAX) provider in the United States is shutting down its WiMAX service and radio towers in November 2015.

Is there any use for their [existing WiMAX modems](http://www.clear.com/support)?

Is WiMAX used anywhere else? If so, might these modems be compatible?

Or do all these devices go to the recycling center/trash heap?

Comment: Is it possible to connect a hotspot to the old clearwire modems and use it as a router? Anyone find a use for the modems now?

Comment: My model has built-in wifi and Ethernet port, and could indeed be used to create a wifi. But such hardware is a dime-a-dozen now. Other hardware would work much better, and be supported with update. So there seems no point in using the CLEAR for such a purpose.

Comment: Good question.  WiMAX went nowhere fast, didn't it?  I remember it was supposed to be the big thing....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be accurate, *Sprint* is shutting down WiMax to use the spectrum for LTE. They were, to my knowledge, the only WiMax operator in the US.  If you read the wiki article you linked, you'd see the [List of WiMAX networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WiMAX_networks). However, that list doesn't mean there are (or were) *operational* networks -- some of the entries list "spectrum licenses".

Other countries do still have WiMax networks, but I doubt you could recode the modem to work on those networks. The clearwire branded gear have 802.1x certificates specific to the Clear network, and no interface for the user to mess with them. A big enough operator might be able to reset them, but why would they bother? (I'd like to see them reused, too. But they're 99% e-waste now.)

Answer (score 2):

Download The clear house modems specs before they close the website.
These modems are made by a company in tiawan, I think the name is GENECOM,
They sell these modems worldwide to different WIMAX operators.
They are reprogrammed by a simple download. You may be able to sell your
modem on ebay to a foreign customer.

I reused the clear telephone adapter with several clients by reprogramming,
they were made by linksys. Clear sold them for $10 each, Linksys sold them
for $40.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I use my clear modem as a regular wifi router.
Power up your old clear modem. Connect to it through wifi signal. Log in to it through browser, type clearmodem/ or 192.168.15.1 in search field. Default password is "admin". Once in there find DHCP and turn it off (uncheck the box). Plug one end of ethernet cable to you ISP router (e.g. Arris) and another end to LAN port of clear modem. This is it. Easy peasy.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There were different models of Clear modems. The most common only had the WiMax antenna and you had to connect it to a separate router. Then there were models that also had an WIFI router built-in.

If your model only has the WiMax antenna it is now a doorstop. While there are networks overseas that may use it the cost of shipping is more than the cost of buying a new modem in those locations. Recycle it properly.

If your model also has the internal WIFI router you can use the directions above, posted by Ilnar Fatylenoz, to disable the modem portion of the unit and use only the WIFI router.